# Attributing a vector to a link

Tags: netlogo

I want to initiate for each (undirected) link two one-dimensional arrays array1 and array2. At each tick, if one of the endpoints satisfies condition1? while the other satisfies condition2?, a random number is generated and the random number and the current tick are saved into the array1 and array2, respectively. I want both arrays to grow in length as the program runs.

How do I initiate such an array for each link and how do I update it while checking for the condition of its endpoints?

For now, I set up the links and turtles using the following

```
turtles-own[
   condition1?
   condition2?
]

links-own [
   array1
   array2
]

to set-up[
   clear-all
   reset-ticks
   make-turtles
   make-nodes ;; creates the nodes
   ask turtles [
      set condition1? true
      set condition2? true 
  ] 
  ask links [
      set array1 []
      set array2 []
  ]
]
```

The go command contains a routine that changes the values of condition1? and condition2?, although that's not really my problem.

To update the array, I'm thinking of:

```
let prob 0
ask turtles[
   ask link-neighbors
   set prob random-float 100
   ;; I don't know what to put here.
   ;; If one of the endpoint satisfies condition1? while the other
   ;; satisfies condition 2, I want prob to be appended to array1
   ;; and the current tick appended to array2
   ]
 ]
```

Perhaps a routine that asks links instead would work?

Answer (score 1):

Whether to do as `ask links` or `ask turtles` depends on how meaningful array1 vs array2 is. Doing from the perspective of turtles means you can always have 'me' testing against condition1 and 'the other' against condition2. But once you are at the turtle, it is easier to run through the turtle's links (`my-links`) rather than the other end turtles (`link-neighbors`).

The way you have created the arrays (lists in NetLogo terminology if you want to check the dictionary for available commands) is fine.

Here's one option, using `fput`, which has the most recent test at the front (front put) of the list. Not tested so may be syntax errors.

```
ask turtles
[ ask my-links
  if [condition1?] of myself and [condition2?] of other-end
  [ set array1 fput random 100 array1
    set array2 fput ticks array2
  ]
]
```

You may want to consider using directed links, so that array1 and array2 don't contain elements for both directions. If so, use `my-out-links`.